# Complex routing issues Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to match complex routes which is causing mismatch, These are my routes file entries.

```
  match 'households/:id/edit'=>'households#edit', :via=>:get, :as=>:edit_household, :id=>/\d{1,5}/
  match 'households/:id' => 'households#update', :via => :put
  match 'households/:id' => 'households#destroy', :via=>:delete
  match 'households/:city_code-:region_code'=>'households#index', :via=>:get, :as=>:households, :city_code=>/[A-Z]{3,5}/, :region_code=>/[A-Z]{0,3}\d{0,5}/
  match 'households/:city_code-:region_code-:h_uid'=>'households#show', :via=>:get, :as=>:household, :city_code=>/[A-Z]{3,5}/, :region_code=>/[A-Z]{0,3}\d{0,5}/
```

Now the problem is that the request

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/households/9/edit
```

is routing to the show controller and the error is generating

Routing Error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"households", :action=>"show", :format=>nil, :city_code=>#<Household id: 9, uid: "0004", house_no: "House No 12", street: "Street 512", address: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing...", region_id: 3, created_at: "2012-01-05 11:06:32", updated_at: "2012-01-05 11:06:32">}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the url is routing to the show controller, as opposed to something on the edit page trying (but failing) to generate a link to a show page ?

Comment: Yes i am sure, When ever i type direct edit url in browser it came to `No route match error`, and in error you can see `show` action is described.

Comment: Is there a backtrace in development.log?

Comment: No backtrace is available in development log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my routes to:

```
  resources :households, :only=>[:index, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
    collection do
      match ':city_code-:region_code-:h_uid'=>'households#show', :via=>:get, :as=>:show, :city_code=>/[A-Z]{3,5}/, :region_code=>/[A-Z]{0,3}\d{0,5}/
    end
  end
```

and every thing is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're passing not the `city_code` to the route helper, but the object:

```
:city_code => #<Household id: 9, uid: "0004", house_no: "House No 12", ... >
```

which is, of course, rejected by the router, as it has a constraint: `:city_code=>/[A-Z]{3,5}/`.

Comment: I do not pass any thing in the view. I am testing it by typing url in the browser. As you can see in the routes , edit route is above the show and url meets the constraints of edit route but still it is going for show.